# What is difference between building a responsive website and mobile first web?

Tags: php, angularjs, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have experience in web applications with php, html, css, jquery, rest services.
I want to take my knowledge to next level. I have intermediate knowledge of angularjs, handlebars, bootstrap, backbone.js.

I have searched for best frameworks/libraries for mobile first app  I found angularjs and another anugularjs for mobile.

Can somebody explain the actual difference between building a responsive website and mobile first web?
Why a responsive website is not fully functional for mobile, if I am right?

Can somebody guide what are the best framework to use for building a mobile first web application?

Regards,
Usman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion "mobile first" is more design concern rather than development. To deliver the best UX you should follow mobile first guidelines. If you have layout designed with "mobile first" approach then you can use any framework to acheive responsivness. Framework will make it easier. That's all.
The responsive is simply adaptive layout(media queries) and fluid/liquid layout(percentages grid). It's not complicated. The hard part is the design.

**You can read more about "mobile first" design here:**
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

**Popular responsive frameworks **

- Twitter Bootstrap
  www.getbootstrap.com
- Foundation
  www.foundation.zurb.com
- Skeleton
  www.getskeleton.com